# WSDL Exception in webservice

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I created my first axis2 webservice and I got following error when I try to invoke the web service through my client which is created using stub.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/wsdl/WSDLException
at com.test.first.TestStub.populateAxisService(TestStub.java:41)
at com.test.first.TestStub.<init>(TestStub.java:88)
at com.test.first.TestStub.<init>(TestStub.java:77)
at com.test.first.TestStub.<init>(TestStub.java:126)
at com.test.first.TestStub.<init>(TestStub.java:118)
at com.test.first.TestTest.main(TestTest.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.wsdl.WSDLException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Laun``cher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 6 more
```

What could be the root cause for this exception?

Note: I have included wsdl4j and log4j libraries.

Comment: Can you show us the code also..??

Answer (score -1):

Likely a classpath issue? Can't find javax.wsdl.WSDLException. Ensure this is available.